# Spark-sql Error in query: Unsupported java type class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, hive, apache-spark-sql

now we transfer hive to spark-sql. we create some UDFs use ETL. when use *FUNC*(X) --Returns an ArrayList. in hive is correct. but the same FUNC use spark-sql throws : Spark-sql Error in query:  Unsupported java type class java.util.ArrayList. below is my simple code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Array_Test extends UDF{

    public static ArrayList<String> evaluate(String jsonArrayStr) {

        ArrayList<String> textList = new ArrayList<String>();
        textList.add(jsonArrayStr);
        return textList;

    }
}
```

can anyone konw why?   we used spark vesrion is SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.171658.hive version is 1.1.0-cdh5.15.2.

Thansk

Comment: Spark can query Hive tables and views as-is. What is there to transfer?

Comment: this UDF  just sample. we use UDF to transfer some data return ArrayList. this udf in hive eveything ok. the same sentence spark-sql excute. throw exception Unsupported java type class java.util.ArrayList

Comment: What if you defined the method to return just a List or an array?

Comment: thanks for you relay. finally we change method return value to string. in spark-sql use split() FUNCX to change string to List.

Comment: I think you could also make a UTDF if you wanted to return a list